# Naming conventions / translation between dpkg and apt packages?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I've been trying to figure out package management in debian a little better.

I figured out that you can list all the packages on your system by using the "apt-cache pkgnames" command:

```
root@t500:/etc# apt-cache pkgnames | less
aspell-ca
libglobus-rls-client5
rkhunter
libmpich-shmem1.0gf
meep
libspring-webmvc-portlet-2.5-java
libindicate-doc
libjetty-extra-java
python-decoratortools
tree-ppuzzle
darkice
cutter-testing-framework-bin
aspell-bg
libsmpeg0
libpng12-dev
```

However, when I try to look up additional information about the packages in dpkg, the same package names are not listed:

```
root@t500:/etc# dpkg-query -W meep
No packages found matching meep.

root@t500:/etc# dpkg-query -W darkice
No packages found matching darkice.
```

I had assumed that apt and dpkg they would at least utilize the same package names, is that not the case?

Is there a way of figuring out what the dpkg name of an apt package is?

Comment: Just one comment, do not use root all the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same name, `apt` is just a frontend to `dpkg`. The issue here is that the commands don't do what you thing they do. As explained in `man apt-cache`:

```
   pkgnames [prefix]
       This command prints the name of each package APT knows. The
       optional argument is a prefix match to filter the name list. The
       output is suitable for use in a shell tab complete function and the
       output is generated extremely quickly. This command is best used
       with the --generate option.

       Note that a package which APT knows of is not necessarily available
       to download, installable or installed, e.g. virtual packages are
       also listed in the generated list.
```

So, `apt-cache pkgnames` lists *all* packages available to the system, irrespective of whether those packages are installed or not.

If you want to list installed packages only, you could use `dpkg -l` or `dpkg-query -l`:

```
   -l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
          List packages matching given pattern. If no package-name-pattern
          is  given,  list all packages in /var/lib/dpkg/status, excluding
          the ones marked as not-installed (i.e.  those  which  have  been
          previously  purged).
```

This means that it will also list those packages that have been removed if their configuration files are still present, i.e. if they were not purged. The second column of the `dpkg-query -l` output is the package status which can be any of

```
          Package status:
            n = Not-installed
            c = Config-files
            H = Half-installed
            U = Unpacked
            F = Half-configured
            W = Triggers-awaiting
            t = Triggers-pending
            i = Installed
```

So, to find those packages that are currently installed, you will want to select those whose status is `i`. To do that, simply `grep` for lines whose 1st character is anything and whose second is `i`:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep '^.i'
```

You can easily check that the two commands are different and that `apt-cache` returns thousands more results than `dpkg`. For example, on my system:

```
$ dpkg-query -l | grep '^.i' | wc -l
3938
$ apt-cache pkgnames | wc -l
39889
```

Comment: Super helpful, thanks.  Your pkgnames comes up with nearly 40k results, while mine only comes up with around 28k. Would that be due to differences in our sources.list files?

Comment: @some1 yes, exactly. Different sources mean different packages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to establish a 'pattern' (with quotes) instead of just writing the name:

```
$ dpkg-query -W 'samba'
samba   
$ dpkg-query -W 'samba*'
samba   
samba-client    
samba-common    2:3.6.9-1ubuntu1.1
samba-common-bin    2:3.6.9-1ubuntu1.1
samba-tools 
samba4-clients  
samba4-common
```

That's why no package appear:

```
$ dpkg-query -W 'rkhunter' 
rkhunter    1.4.0-2
```

Other things that may work:

```
dpkg-query -W '*a'
dpkg-query -W 'a*b*'
dpkg-query -W '?a*'
```

etc.

> Normal shell wildchars are allowed in package-name-pattern. Please note you
>                 will probably have to quote package-name-pattern to prevent the shell from performing  filename
>                 expansion.